# View content in secure file

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to view the content of a Secure File? These are the ones we upload under Pipelines --> Library. It lets me add new and delete existing ones but not view/edit existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is by design that you can't view the contents of the secure file. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops):

> The contents of the secure files are encrypted and can only be used during the build or release pipeline by referencing them from a task.

Comment: I think you are right: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-edit-a-secure-file/376314?space=21&entry=suggestion&dialog=comment